# Access JSP Output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

There exists a JSP file that creates output I need to retrieve.

I would like to write a function in which I can pass the url of this jsp file and it will return the jsp's output data.

Example:

var a_String = getJspData("http://somedomainonadifferentserver.com/getData.jsp");

Most of the results I've found while searching for a solution are to embed the jsp in the javascript, or to get javascript variables within the jsp. I just want to get the data the jsp gets within my own script using either javascript or jquery. Any ideas? The data output is in JSON but I can accept it as either JSON or string, makes no difference to me.

Comment: If you are not embedding the Javascript in a JSP, then it sounds like AJAX is what you are looking for.  There is plenty of good material out there on AJAX.

Comment: Do you have access to that other domain? If you do, then set the output to JSONP format which will let you consume it cross-domain. Alternatively, enable CORS on that server.

Comment: We do have access, yes.Someone else already mentioned the possibility of JSONP, but the AJAX thing is new.